# How do I stop duplicate api calls in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a very simple API call when clicking on `minister` router link. It displays some data when minister page is open. But I see whenever I came back to that page either from the homepage or any other page the API keeps loading again.

[image: duplicate api calls]

### minister.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiReadService } from "../apiReadService.service";

interface mydata{
  allMinisters: Object
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ministers',
  templateUrl: './ministers.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ministers.component.scss']
})
export class MinistersComponent implements OnInit {

  allData:Object = [];

  constructor(private apiRead: ApiReadService) {

  }
  ngOnInit(){
  this.apiRead.getData().subscribe(data=>{
            this.allData  = data.allMinisters;
    }); 
  }
}
```

### apiReadSerivce.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/Http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ApiReadService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getData(){
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8081/allMinisters')
    }
}
```

Comment: there can be 2 first for the options and second actual call, clear your console and then route to that page and check how many requests are going.

Comment: only  1 at a time. The api loads every time I come back to that page

Comment: `ngOnInit` is called every time the component is created... which is every time you view the page. As you are calling `this.apiRead.getData` in `ngOnInit` you need a way to cache the data, which Simon_Weaver has shown below... although there are many ways to cache data client side.

Comment: You can use this very efficiently - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cacheable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way - if you only ever want the data to load once is something like this:

```
import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';

export class ApiReadService {
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

   ministers$ = this.http.get('http://localhost:8081/allMinisters')
                         .pipe(shareReplay(1))

   getData() {
      return this.ministers$;
   }
}
```

Once the results have been returned once it will get 'cached' by the `shareReplay(1)` and that same value returned each time.

Comment: If you're new to Angular I strongly recommend reading as much as you can about RxJS. Try to find articles specifically related to Angular, because they'll be more useful - or just stackoverflow questions. Understanding RxJS really helps take advantage of Angular's potential like nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. will start angular tutorial. Also do you mind telling me if I need to import something fro shareReplay(1)

Comment: Thanks your updated answer solve my problem. But if I update my api during the period, does it show updated answer?

Comment: you mean if you add a new minister - no it wouldn't. You'd need to decide when to refresh this - and that in itself can get surprisingly complicated. But if you only want to load it once this would work.

Comment: okay I got it thanks. I need to refresh the page. Also any reason why did you add that $ sign after minister ? is that mandatory ?

Comment: Not mandatory, it's just a convention followed for naming Observables

Comment: this is a very neat trick for current purpose